# C accessing 1d array as 2d array

Tags: arrays, c

I have an array that represents an image of RGB pixels:

```c
struct pix{
  unsigned char red;
  unsigned char green;
  unsigned char blue
}

struct pix *pixels = malloc(800*600*sizeof(struct pix));
```

The array `pixels` represents an 800x600 image, with values stored as R,G,B triplets. Is there any way to treat this 1-dimensional array as if it were a 2-dimensional array with width 800 and height 600, so that e.g. `pixels[0][0].red=255` is a valid operation?

Comment: If it really is 800x600, why not `struct pix (*pixels)[800] = malloc(600 * sizeof *pixels)` ?

Comment: Can we assume that, in general, the dimensions are *not* known at compile time (800x600 beeing just an example)?

Comment: Assuming that your compiler supports variable length arrays (VLA), you can just replace the numbers with variables: `struct pix (*pixels)[cols] = malloc(rows * sizeof *pixels);`

Comment: Does http://c-faq.com/aryptr/ help you solve the problem, especially [subsection 13](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/ptrtoarray.html)?

Comment: `struct pix *p[800]; for( int i=0; i < 800; i++ ){ p[i] = pixels + 600 * i; }`  Then you can reference `p[0][0].red`

Comment: @WhozCraig do you mean `malloc(600*sizeof(struct pix))`?

Comment: @2lean4 , no, WhozCraig means `sizeof *pizels`, which is the size of 800 structs, since in that comment `pixels` is a pointer to arrays of 800 structs.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: That is a bad method and should not be recommended. As written, it uses automatic storage duration, so it cannot be returned to a caller like the original can. And it causes matrix lookups to use multiple pointer indirection, which is bad for prediction in some processors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
struct pix (*pixels)[800] = malloc(600 * sizeof *pixels);
```

This declares `pixels` to be a pointer to an array of 800 `struct pix` and allocates 600 of them. Then you can access the element in row `i` and column `j` as `pixels[i][j]`, and its members with `pixels[i][j].red`. (Do not forget to check the return value of `malloc` to see if it succeeded or failed.)

In many C implementations, `800` can be replaced by a variable instead of a constant, and it will still work.

When allocating, preferably use `sizeof *MyPointer` as shown here, rather than `sizeof (MyType)`. Then, if you ever need to change the type of `MyPointer`, there is one place fewer you need to edit.

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for, thanks. Is there any way to swap around i and j while keeping the underlying data structure the same? so like i can do pixels[x][y], essentially? not exactly necessary, but it'd be more intuitive.

Comment: @2lean4: What do you mean by swapping `i` and `j`? There is no `x` or `y` in your question or my answer, so I do not know what `pixels[x][y]` is supposed to mean.

Comment: er sorry, i meant in terms of x-coordinate,y-coordinate, rather than the other way around

Answer (score 0):

This uses a similar pointer to what Eric used, but I've added an array descriptor `struct` that can be passed around easily.

That is, from `main`, how do you pass the array to subfunctions? Especially, if you have to have multiple arrays that have differing dimensions?

The syntax of (e.g.):

```
struct pix (*pixels)[width] = malloc(sizeof(*pixels) * height);
```

can be cumbersome.

It can be simplified with a small bit of macro trickery.

Here's some code that illustrates the benefits of a `struct` and the convenience of being able to do true 2D indexing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint8_t u8;
typedef uint32_t u32;

#define sysfault(_fmt...) \
    do { \
        printf(_fmt); \
        exit(1); \
    } while (0)

// pixel control
typedef struct pix {
    u8 red;
    u8 green;
    u8 blue;
} pix_t;

// pixel array control
typedef struct arr {
    size_t arr_width;
    size_t arr_height;
    pix_t *arr_pixels;
} arr_t;

#define ARR2DPTR(_arr) \
    pix_t (*_arr##ptr)[_arr->arr_width] = \
        (__typeof__(_arr##ptr)) _arr->arr_pixels

arr_t *
arrnew(size_t width,size_t height)
{
    arr_t *arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr));

    arr->arr_width = width;
    arr->arr_height = height;
    arr->arr_pixels = malloc(sizeof(*arr->arr_pixels) * width * height);

    return arr;
}

void
pixpack(pix_t *pix,u32 off)
{

    pix->red = (off >> 16);
    pix->green = (off >> 8);
    pix->blue = (off >> 0);
}

u32
pixunpack(const pix_t *pix)
{
    u32 off = 0;

    off |= ((u32) pix->red) << 16;
    off |= ((u32) pix->green) << 8;
    off |= ((u32) pix->blue) << 0;

    return off;
}

void
arrfill(arr_t *arr)
{
    pix_t *arrptr = arr->arr_pixels;
    u32 off = 0;

    for (size_t y = 0;  y < arr->arr_height;  ++y) {
        for (size_t x = 0;  x < arr->arr_width;  ++x, ++off)
            pixpack(&arrptr[(y * arr->arr_width) + x],off);
    }
}

void
chk2ptr(arr_t *arr)
{
    ARR2DPTR(arr);
    u32 offexp = 0;
    u32 offact;

    for (size_t y = 0;  y < arr->arr_height;  ++y) {
        for (size_t x = 0;  x < arr->arr_width;  ++x, ++offexp) {
            offact = pixunpack(&arrptr[y][x]);
            if (offact != offexp)
                sysfault("chk2ptr: y=%zu x=%zu offexp=%u offact=%u\n",
                    y,x,offexp,offact);
        }
    }
}

void
chk1ptr(arr_t *arr)
{
    pix_t *arrptr = arr->arr_pixels;
    u32 offexp = 0;
    u32 offact;

    for (size_t y = 0;  y < arr->arr_height;  ++y) {
        for (size_t x = 0;  x < arr->arr_width;  ++x, ++offexp) {
            offact = pixunpack(&arrptr[(y * arr->arr_width) + x]);
            if (offact != offexp)
                sysfault("chk1ptr: y=%zu x=%zu offexp=%u offact=%u\n",
                    y,x,offexp,offact);
        }
    }
}

int
main(void)
{

    arr_t *arr = arrnew(20,10);
    arrfill(arr);

    chk1ptr(arr);
    chk2ptr(arr);

    return 0;
}
```